# GhostScript Error Converting a PDF to an Image with ImageMagick

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, ghostscript, pdf-conversion

I'm getting the following error when running the following command:

```
convert -colorspace rgb -density 240 file.pdf file.png
```

> Error: /invalidaccess in --run-- Operand stack: --dict:6/15(L)-- fn3
>   21 --dict:6/6(L)-- --dict:6/6(L)-- BEFQKQ+ArialMT
>   --dict:11/12(ro)(G)-- --nostringval-- CIDFontObject --dict:7/7(L)-- --dict:7/7(L)-- 1937 --dict:7/7(L)-- --nostringval-- PDFCIDFontName BEFQKQ+ArialMT Execution stack: %interp_exit .runexec2 --nostringval--
>   --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 2 %stopped_push --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- false 1 %stopped_push 1846 1 3 %oparray_pop 1845 1 3 %oparray_pop 1829 1 3 %oparray_pop
>   --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 2 1 7 --nostringval-- %for_pos_int_continue --nostringval-- --nostringval-- false 1
>   %stopped_push --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval--
>   %array_continue --nostringval-- false 1 %stopped_push --nostringval--
>   %loop_continue --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval--
>   --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- %array_continue --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- Dictionary stack: --dict:1155/1684(ro)(G)-- --dict:1/20(G)-- --dict:75/200(L)-- --dict:75/200(L)-- --dict:106/127(ro)(G)-- --dict:286/300(ro)(G)-- --dict:23/25(L)-- --dict:4/6(L)-- --dict:21/40(L)-- --dict:1/1(ro)(G)-- --dict:1/1(ro)(G)-- Current allocation mode is local

How do I solve it?

Comment: You need to specify what version of Ghostscript you are using, what the *Ghostscript* command line is, and post a URL to the file demonstrating the problem. Other than that, all I can say is something attempted to access a compound object which was created in a different VM allocation mode, or which is readonly or similar. It appears to be a font, but beyond that its rather hard to say anything useful.

Comment: v8.70 or v9.10. I used the above command, which is ImageMagick, but it calls GhostScript for PDF conversion.

Comment: Both those versions are out of date, the current version is 9.15. I'm aware that ImageMagick calls Ghostscript to do the rendering, which is why I emphasised needing the Ghostscript command line..... Also, the PDF file causing the problem, its impossible to debug a problem without seeing it.